# angularjs template ng-view

Tags: html, templates, angularjs

Anyone can please tell me what im doing wrong here:

i just update the library, and seems that the code broke for some reason it's not doing anything.

angular library

html5 code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
    <h1 id="logo"><a href="#/home"></a></h1>

    <div id="menu">
        <a ng-click="setRoute('home')" class="btn">Home</a>
        <a ng-click="setRoute('about')" class="btn">about</a>
    <a ng-click="setRoute('experiments')" class="btn">Experiments</a>
    </div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
<!-- //top -->
<div class="shadow"></div>

<div id="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

angular.js

```
 angular.module('WebSite', []).
    config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/about', {templateUrl:'folder/test.html', controller:AboutCtrl}).
            when('/experiments', {templateUrl:'folder/test.html', controller:ExperimentsCtrl   }).
            when('/home', {templateUrl:'folder/test.html', controller:HomeCtrl   }).
            otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});
    });

function AboutCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'About Page';
    $scope.body = 'This is the about page body';
}

function ExperimentsCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Experiments Page';
    $scope.body = 'This is the about experiments body';
}

function HomeCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Home Page';
    $scope.body = 'This is the about home body';
}
```

Comment: Where is the setRoute function defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to use ng-app to setup the angular application with your module. Maybe you already did, but it is not part of the snippet you posted:

```
<html ng-app="WebSite">
```

Also, about the setRoute(), I don't know where you copy that from, but you don't need it. Just use the href with the hash, for example:

```
<a href="#/about" class="btn">about</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out the source from github at https://github.com/simpulton/angular-website-routes

There is no changeRoute method. After some dialog, I realized it was best to handle the anchors tags as naturally as possible.

Your menu element should look like this

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#/home" class="btn">Home</a>
    <a href="#/about" class="btn">About</a>
    <a href="#/experiments" class="btn">Experiments</a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!